# Magento 2.4.2: Is it possible to store the vendor addresses in Magento admin?

Tags: magento2.4

Just wanted to know if it is possible to store the list of vendors in Magento. These vendors are the ones who ship the products ordered on my Magento site.

Comment: Not by default. Theoretically, you could store them as customers, perhaps in a designated customer group. That would make them available to custom programming, e.g. to create reports, etc.

Comment: Maybe the "custom variables" part of magento is something, that could help you. You can specify custom variables and get the values from almost everywhere (pages, cms-blocks, pthml blocks etc.)

System -> Custom Variables

Comment: @Mario, I think your recommendation seems to be the one I should go for.

Comment: @jiheison, thanks for the possible solution. Let me try the other solution first.

Comment: would you mind, if I add my comment as an answer?

Comment: Please go ahead and turn it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the "custom variables" part of magento is something, that could help you. You can specify custom variables and get the values from almost everywhere (pages, cms-blocks, pthml files etc.)

`System -> Custom Variables`

Comment: Can this custom variable an array variable too?

Comment: I dont think so - depending on how you want to use the variable, you could trick the system by writing a json-string into the html-value and parse the json inside a phtml file.
That wont work in a cms-block or cms-page.

Comment: This piece of information is useful